# Why is it showing the error 'The assigned value is never used'?

Tags: java, error-handling, syntax-error, return-value, variable-assignment

I coded a program in JAVA to find the greatest `integer` among three numbers. How can I eliminate that instruction by the IDE? and do I need to worry about is?
[image]

Comment: You don't need to explicitly assign a value say `0` to your `result` variable because you are initialising it with the largest of three numbers already with your logic. So in a way, the value `0` will never be used and that's what the compiler is suggesting to you. It's what's called a warning and can be ignored

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning, and you should make sure that you understand why the warning is there. (In this case, it usually makes your code cleaner to remove unused instructions.)

Comment: Don’t ignore warnings. Move the declaration to the line where the variable is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you have assigned `0` on the `result` variable and it doesn't have any impact on the code. This `0` value of `result` has never been used as you changed the variable afterwards without using it.

Comment: Thanks brother, Now i have assigned 'int' datatype directly to the 'result' with previously storing '0' in it and the warning is resolved noe.